# What size/color wire nut?

Tags: electrical

I am replacing a 220v 40a hot tub circuit with a 120v 15a hot tub.  8ga is wired to the box.  Im replacing the breaker with a 20a GFI 120v and caping the unused line. Question is it within code to wire nut a 12 ga wire at the receiptcal end to the 8ga wire and if so, what color screw cap?

The 8ga hard wire feed is 20a but the receptacle terminals are 12ga max.

Any comments if this is wrong?  Runnjng a new 12ga supply wire isn't easy or cheap.

Thanks.

Comment: A 120V/15A hot tub won't be very hot, unless it uses natural gas for heat.

Comment: They exist but they’re not ideal. The usual M.O. is that they can’t run the heat and the pump at the same time. They should be able to get up to temperature if the insulation is good but they’re not good for long sessions since they can’t add heat while the pump is running.

Comment: Definitely check if this hot tub can be converted to 240V. Many can be. It’s easy and very much worth it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not wrong, though there are better ways to do this. *e.g.* put in a subpanel and have more power available at that location, or put in a 20A dual to feed the cable and have an MWBC for two (GFCI) outlets, each with 20A available there, anyway - **but if you don't need it, then you don't need it.**

Color is not a completely consistent guide as different makers and products within a maker vary somewhat.

Just look for one that lists 1 8AWG and 1 12AWG as a listed application for the nut in the long chart on the side of the box. Probably a big blue, but refer to the second point here and the sentence before this before buying those.

Without doing an exhaustive search through [this chart for one maker](https://www.idealind.com/content/dam/electrical/assets/WireTermination/P-5560%20IDEAL%20UL%20Approved%20Wire%20Combination%20Listing03.05.21.pdf), I can see multiple options that list 1 (or more) 8 AWG and 1 (or more) 12 AWG as UL-listed applications. You don't want one that does not list the 1&1 combo, but otherwise multiple types/sizes will work, and there are other makers, though this one is *arguably* the dominant USA maker (or marketer) at present.

Comment: Thanks, the available chart shows the big blue can do 3 -8's but I'll do some math before using any.

Comment: Note that too big is as bad as too small. See https://www.idealind.com/content/dam/electrical/assets/WireTermination/P-5560%20IDEAL%20UL%20Approved%20Wire%20Combination%20Listing03.05.21.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You're always allowed to use larger wire than is required for a circuit.  So 15-20A on #8 is fine.

When UL approves electrical equipment, they also approve detailed instructions that explain exactly how it is to be used.  Per NEC 110.3 you can't use it any other way.

When they approve wire nuts, they approve a very exhaustive list of every single wire size combination tested and approved.  [Here is one for Ideal.](https://rexel-cdn.com/products/file1033idealconnectorullistedwirecombinations.pdf?i=416EA8D6-250E-4489-AD1A-E9193F9E68E4)

If that doesn't bring it up, try searching "wire nut UL listed wire combinations" (no quotes).